# Alibaba Cloud ECS always increasing disk space?

Tags: storage, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I need help with my Alibaba Cloud Elastic Compute Service!

[screenshot of df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pyUo.png)

[screenshot of iotop -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTBpW.jpg)

My storage was only 40GB and I used 33GB, on the next day it became fully consumed. The usage was at 40GB even though I had not uploaded any files.

I decided to increase my storage to 60GB, but 3 days later it has become fully consumed again.

I badly need help.

Thank you.

Comment: So.. *what* is using the space? Knowing *where* the usage is will be a useful start..

Comment: I was confused what is happening. Because Alibaba ECS is increased automatically when it has a free space.

Comment: My Laravel size is only 12.0GB, and the Alibaba ECS is 60GB. How it totally consumed by 12.0GB.

Answer (score 0):

Free up some space and install [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/). Using `iotop -a` you can leave it running for a while and check back to find which processes are consuming your disk.

Comment: I can't install it because it says "You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/"

Comment: `/var` must be out of space, you will need to free some up. Check `du -cha /var/tmp/` maybe there is some space to be had.

Comment: It says 4.0k Total.

Comment: That's nothing, check the same way in `/var/log/` maybe something is flooding your logs

Comment: I got 1.2GB Total. Is't okay to delete this?

Comment: Any specific logs that are much larger than the others?

Comment: It has 6 of 89M "/var/log/journal/2989f5b21b69559532cbb72e5d0b41b7/system@000000000000000"

Comment: Can you post the output of `df -h` into the question? Also remove one of the older log files so you can install iotiop, 89M should be enough.

Comment: Looking at the iotop screencap it seems to be `php artisan` and `mysqld` eating up the space. Look into whatever you have got running on those services and examine their logs.

Comment: Is that really the cause? Because my laravel size is only 12GB.

Comment: In your screencap iotop shows those processes as having written the most to disk. I can't say with no visibility if it's really the cause, but they are definitely leading in disk writes. I'd start by investigating their data dirs and seeing if they are growing/grew rapidly.